# OLED Test for USBSTK5515 with CCSv6

Tags: signal-processing

I am trying to run the test code for the OLED display simulation on the DSP board TMSC320C5515 eZdsp UsbStick, variant "USBSTK5515".

I have included the bsl folder and needed included libraries and header files through the spectrum website. Now the problem is that I am being unable to compile; I am getting the error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project OLED ****

"G:\\TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6\\ccsv6\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k all 
'Building file: ../main.c'
'Invoking: C5500 Compiler'
"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/bin/cl55" -v5515 --memory_model=large -g --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk5515_BSL_RevA/usbstk5515_v1/include" --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk1151_Demo_RevA/USBSTK5515_demo/source/USB_Stick_Sample/inc" --include_path="G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/include" --define=c5515 --display_error_number --diag_warning=225 --ptrdiff_size=16 --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="main.pp"  "../main.c"
'Finished building: ../main.c'
' '
'Building file: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515.c'
'Invoking: C5500 Compiler'
"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/bin/cl55" -v5515 --memory_model=large -g --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk5515_BSL_RevA/usbstk5515_v1/include" --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk1151_Demo_RevA/USBSTK5515_demo/source/USB_Stick_Sample/inc" --include_path="G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/include" --define=c5515 --display_error_number --diag_warning=225 --ptrdiff_size=16 --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515.pp" --obj_directory="usbstk5515bsl/bsl"  "../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515.c"
'Finished building: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515.c'
' '
'Building file: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_gpio.c'
'Invoking: C5500 Compiler'
"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/bin/cl55" -v5515 --memory_model=large -g --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk5515_BSL_RevA/usbstk5515_v1/include" --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk1151_Demo_RevA/USBSTK5515_demo/source/USB_Stick_Sample/inc" --include_path="G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/include" --define=c5515 --display_error_number --diag_warning=225 --ptrdiff_size=16 --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_gpio.pp" --obj_directory="usbstk5515bsl/bsl"  "../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_gpio.c"
'Finished building: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_gpio.c'
' '
'Building file: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_i2c.c'
'Invoking: C5500 Compiler'
"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/bin/cl55" -v5515 --memory_model=large -g --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk5515_BSL_RevA/usbstk5515_v1/include" --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk1151_Demo_RevA/USBSTK5515_demo/source/USB_Stick_Sample/inc" --include_path="G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/include" --define=c5515 --display_error_number --diag_warning=225 --ptrdiff_size=16 --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_i2c.pp" --obj_directory="usbstk5515bsl/bsl"  "../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_i2c.c"
'Finished building: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_i2c.c'
' '
'Building file: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_led.c'
'Invoking: C5500 Compiler'
"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/bin/cl55" -v5515 --memory_model=large -g --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk5515_BSL_RevA/usbstk5515_v1/include" --include_path="C:/Users/SOURINDU/Desktop/usbstk1151_Demo_RevA/USBSTK5515_demo/source/USB_Stick_Sample/inc" --include_path="G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/include" --define=c5515 --display_error_number --diag_warning=225 --ptrdiff_size=16 --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_led.pp" --obj_directory="usbstk5515bsl/bsl"  "../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_led.c"
'Finished building: ../usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_led.c'
' '
'Building target: OLED.out'
'Invoking: C5500 Linker'
"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/bin/cl55" -v5515 --memory_model=large -g --define=c5515 --display_error_number --diag_warning=225 --ptrdiff_size=16 -z -m"OLED.map" --stack_size=0x200 --heap_size=0x400 -i"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/lib" -i"G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/c5500_4.4.1/include" --reread_libs --display_error_number --warn_sections --xml_link_info="OLED_linkInfo.xml" --rom_model --sys_stacksize=0x200 -o "OLED.out" "./main.obj" "./usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515.obj" "./usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_gpio.obj" "./usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_i2c.obj" "./usbstk5515bsl/bsl/usbstk5515_led.obj" "../lnkx.cmd" "../usbstk5515bsl/usbstk5515bsl.lib"  -l"libc.a" -l"rts55x.lib" 
<Linking>

 undefined first referenced                                                                                 
  symbol       in file                                                                                      
 --------- ----------------                                                                                 
 _main     G:\TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6\ccsv6\tools\compiler\c5500_4.4.1\lib\rts55x.lib<args_main.obj>

error #10234-D: unresolved symbols remain

error #10010: errors encountered during linking; "OLED.out" not built
>> Compilation failure
gmake: *** [OLED.out] Error 1
gmake: Target `all' not remade because of errors.

**** Build Finished ****
```

And in the problem window :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
#10010 errors encountered during linking; "OLED.out" not built  OLED            C/C++ Problem
<a href="file:/G:/TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6/ccsv6/tools/compiler/dmed/HTML/10234.html">#10234-D</a>  unresolved symbols remain    OLED            C/C++ Problem
unresolved symbol _main, first referenced in G:\TheDevelopmentKitCodeComposerv6\ccsv6\tools\compiler\c5500_4.4.1\lib\rts55x.lib<args_main.obj>  OLED            C/C++ Problem
```

My Code as downloaded from spectrum website is

```
/*
 *  Copyright 2010 by Spectrum Digital Incorporated.
 *  All rights reserved. Property of Spectrum Digital Incorporated.
 */

/*
 *  OSD9616 OLED Test
 *
 */

#include "usbstk5515.h"
//#include "usbstk5515_led.h"
#include "usbstk5515_i2c.h"
#include "lcd.h"
#include "usbstk5515_gpio.h"

#define OSD9616_I2C_ADDR 0x3C    // OSD9616 I2C address

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 *                                                                          *
 *  Int16 OSD9616_send( Uint16 comdat, Uint16 data )                        *
 *                                                                          *
 *      Sends 2 bytes of data to the OSD9616                                *
 *                                                                          *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
Int16 OSD9616_send( Uint16 comdat, Uint16 data )
{
    Uint8 cmd[2];
    cmd[0] = comdat & 0x00FF;     // Specifies whether data is Command or Data
    cmd[1] = data;                // Command / Data

    return USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 2 );
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 *                                                                          *
 *  Int16 OSD9616_multiSend( Uint16 comdat, Uint16 data )                   *
 *                                                                          *
 *      Sends multiple bytes of data to the OSD9616                         *
 *                                                                          *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
Int16 OSD9616_multiSend( Uint8* data, Uint16 len )
{
    Uint16 x;
    Uint8 cmd[10];
    for(x=0;x<len;x++)               // Command / Data
    {
        cmd[x] = data[x];
    }
    return USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, len );
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 *                                                                          *
 *  Int16 printLetter(Uint16 l1,Uint16 l2,Uint16 l3,Uint16 l4)              *
 *                                                                          *
 *      Send 4 bytes representing a Character                               *
 *                                                                          *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
Int16 printLetter(Uint16 l1,Uint16 l2,Uint16 l3,Uint16 l4)
{
    OSD9616_send(0x40,l1);
    OSD9616_send(0x40,l2);
    OSD9616_send(0x40,l3);
    OSD9616_send(0x40,l4);
    OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);
    return 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 *                                                                          *
 *  Int16 oled_test()                                                       *
 *                                                                          *
 *      Testing function for the OSD9616 display                            *
 *                                                                          *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
Int16 oled_test()
{
    Int16 i, i2c_err;
    Uint8 cmd[10];    // For multibyte commands

    /* Initialize I2C */
    USBSTK5515_I2C_init( );

    /* Initialize LCD power */
    USBSTK5515_GPIO_setDirection( 12, 1 );  // Output
    USBSTK5515_GPIO_setOutput( 12, 1 );     // Enable 13V

    /* Initialize OSD9616 display */
    i2c_err = OSD9616_send(0x00,0x00); // Set low column address
    i2c_err = OSD9616_send(0x00,0x10); // Set high column address
    if(i2c_err)  // Don't setup display if not connected
        return 1;

    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x40); // Set start line address

    cmd[0] = 0x00 & 0x00FF;  // Set contrast control register
    cmd[1] = 0x81;
    cmd[2] = 0x7f;
    USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 3 );

    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xa1); // Set segment re-map 95 to 0
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xa6); // Set normal display

    cmd[0] = 0x00 & 0x00FF;  // Set multiplex ratio(1 to 16)
    cmd[1] = 0xa8;
    cmd[2] = 0x0f;
    USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 3 );

    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xd3); // Set display offset
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x00); // Not offset
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xd5); // Set display clock divide ratio/oscillator frequency
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xf0); // Set divide ratio

    cmd[0] = 0x00 & 0x00FF;  // Set pre-charge period
    cmd[1] = 0xd9;
    cmd[2] = 0x22;
    USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 3 );

    cmd[0] = 0x00 & 0x00FF;  // Set com pins hardware configuration
    cmd[1] = 0xda;
    cmd[2] = 0x02;
    USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 3 );

    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xdb); // Set vcomh
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x49); // 0.83*vref

    cmd[0] = 0x00 & 0x00FF;  //--set DC-DC enable
    cmd[1] = 0x8d;
    cmd[2] = 0x14;
    USBSTK5515_I2C_write( OSD9616_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 3 );

    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xaf); // Turn on oled panel

    /* Fill page 0 */
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x00);   // Set low column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x10);   // Set high column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xb0+0); // Set page for page 0 to page 5
    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0xff);
    }
    /* Write to page 0 */
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x00);   // Set low column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x10);   // Set high column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xb0+0); // Set page for page 0 to page 5
    for(i=0;i<22;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);  // Spaces
    }
    printLetter(0x32,0x49,0x49,0x26);  // S
    printLetter(0x01,0x7F,0x01,0x01);  // T
    printLetter(0x7F,0x30,0x0E,0x7F);  // N
    printLetter(0x41,0x49,0x49,0x7F);  // E
    printLetter(0x7F,0x06,0x06,0x7F);  // M
    printLetter(0x3F,0x40,0x40,0x3F);  // U
    printLetter(0x46,0x29,0x19,0x7F);  // R
    printLetter(0x01,0x7F,0x01,0x01);  // T
    printLetter(0x32,0x49,0x49,0x26);  // S
    printLetter(0x7F,0x30,0x0E,0x7F);  // N
    printLetter(0x00,0x7F,0x00,0x00);  // I
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);  // Spaces
    }
    printLetter(0x32,0x49,0x49,0x26);  // S
    printLetter(0x7C,0x09,0x0A,0x7C);  // A
    printLetter(0x63,0x1C,0x1C,0x63);  // X
    printLetter(0x41,0x49,0x49,0x7F);  // E
    printLetter(0x01,0x7F,0x01,0x01);  // T

    for(i=0;i<23;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);  // Spaces
    }
    /* Fill page 1*/
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x00);   // Set low column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x10);   // Set high column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xb0+1); // Set page for page 0 to page 5
    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0xff);
    }

    /* Write to page 1*/
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x00);   // Set low column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x10);   // Set high column address
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0xb0+1); // Set page for page 0 to page 5
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);
    }
    printLetter(0x41,0x22,0x14,0x7F);  // K
    printLetter(0x22,0x41,0x41,0x3E);  // C
    printLetter(0x00,0x7F,0x00,0x00);  // I
    printLetter(0x01,0x7F,0x01,0x01);  // T
    printLetter(0x32,0x49,0x49,0x26);  // S
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);  // Spaces
    }
    printLetter(0x36,0x49,0x49,0x7F);  // B
    printLetter(0x32,0x49,0x49,0x26);  // S
    printLetter(0x3F,0x40,0x40,0x3F);  // U
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);  // Spaces
    }
    printLetter(0x06,0x09,0x09,0x7F);  // P
    printLetter(0x32,0x49,0x49,0x26);  // S
    printLetter(0x3E,0x41,0x41,0x7F);  // D
    printLetter(0x43,0x4D,0x51,0x61);  // Z
    printLetter(0x10,0x58,0x58,0x30);  // e
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);  // Spaces
    }
    printLetter(0x31,0x49,0x49,0x2F);  // 5
    printLetter(0x00,0x7F,0x00,0x00);  // 1
    printLetter(0x31,0x49,0x49,0x2F);  // 5
    printLetter(0x31,0x49,0x49,0x2F);  // 5
    printLetter(0x22,0x41,0x41,0x3E);  // C

    for(i=0;i<23;i++)
    {
        OSD9616_send(0x40,0x00);       // Spaces
    }
    /* Set vertical and horizontal scrolling */
    cmd[0] = 0x00;
    cmd[1] = 0x29;  // Vertical and Right Horizontal Scroll
    cmd[2] = 0x00;  // Dummy byte
    cmd[3] = 0x00;  // Define start page address
    cmd[4] = 0x03;  // Set time interval between each scroll step
    cmd[5] = 0x01;  // Define end page address
    cmd[6] = 0x01;  // Vertical scrolling offset
    OSD9616_multiSend( cmd, 7 );
    OSD9616_send(0x00,0x2f);
    /* Keep first 8 rows from vertical scrolling  */
    cmd[0] = 0x00;
    cmd[1] = 0xa3;  // Set Vertical Scroll Area
    cmd[2] = 0x08;  // Set No. of rows in top fixed area
    cmd[3] = 0x08;  // Set No. of rows in scroll area
    OSD9616_multiSend( cmd, 4 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DikeshGandi: If you improve a question, please don't make it **worse** to read.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackOverflow. Are you sure it's ok to publish Spectrum Digital Inc's code? If you don't think it is, you might want to remove it from your question.

Comment: hi i want to learn and solve the problem, i downloaded the CCS from TI website and will be using the information for the purpose of education and research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bit late now, but I think the problem is that you don't have a main function defined to call any of the functions, hence message "unresolved symbol _main".
Not familiar with that particular board, but the example that came with my ezdspc5535 had 2 c files, one of which had a main and examples of how to call the functions in oled_test.c